# How do I go about building an FPGA bitcoin miner?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, homework, hardware

For one of my classes, I was thinking about making an FPGA bitcoin miner but I'm not really sure where I should start. Are there any tutorials or textbooks that would help me understand how I should go about this?

EDIT: Sorry about the confusion. For the final project of my hardware design class, we're given free reign to work on any project involving FPGAs so I thought it would be pretty cool to make a bitcoin miner. So far in the class, we have covered all of the fundamentals of working with FPGAs and recently for our midterm project, we had to make a 32 bit MIPS processor with pipelining in Verilog.

Comment: Do you understand the algorithm(s) used to mine bitcoins? That should be your starting point.

Comment: This site rule: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.* <-- this is usually extended to cover any question asking for recommendations of tutorials/books as well.

Comment: *How do I go about…* You don't. If someone with no experience could build a cost-effective miner, someone else would have done so already, and increased the hardness of mining more bitcoin further. I'm always amazed by how bad the average cryptocurrency fans are at the two core competences of what they root for: basic statistics and basic economy.

Comment: In contrast to the other commenters, I think this is an excellent thing to think about for coursework, and I posted an academic thesis, very suited for an academic assignment.  If your course is FPGA design, implementing any appropriate level part of it is a great project.  As others have said, if you're actually trying to mine bitcoin, forget it, you don't have the resources of the existing miners.

Comment: Snowball: could you describe what course it is and what progress you've made so far?  We might be able to reopen this if you focus your question a bit more.

Comment: This question is closed because you're asking for a very broad question and because you're asking for tutorials, which isn't allowed. If you can make a more specific question, it may be re-opened.

Comment: Forget bitcoin mining for a moment - if you've never used an FPGA before then you might need to start by making the FPGA work *at all*! Make it blink an LED, first. Getting from zero to blinky already isn't trivial, if you're not familiar with FPGAs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller lol yeah this project is mostly just for academic purposes. I thought it would be an interesting thing to do for the final project of my hardware class

Comment: @snowball then I'm all for reopening it! Please explain exactly what your state of considerations is, which courses you have done to build up design experience, and ask a precise question, based on research of what needs to be done and your own understanding of how to approach that!

Comment: I can't recommend doing anything with cryptocurrency at all. Even if you *don't* care about the social and environmental problems it's been causing, it's currently in the middle of a sharp crash that it's unlikely to recover from. Or at least I personally hope it doesn't recover from.

Comment: @Hearth who cares? the task is to implement an algorithm, not to actually mine bitcoins.

Answer (score 5):

*Purely as academic exercise, this seems a very interesting project.  As everyone has said, if you're trying to do real mining, think again: other very well-funded people are way ahead of you and there is almost no way to catch up with them.*

A lot comes down to optimising the [SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) calculation, so you'll want to think about how to do those functions in your FPGA logic.

Start by reading

- Rahul P. Naik, 2013. *Optimising the SHA256 Hashing Algorithm for
  Faster and More Efficient Bitcoin Mining*, MSc Thesis, University College London. [online](http://www.nicolascourtois.com/bitcoin/Optimising%20the%20SHA256%20Hashing%20Algorithm%20for%20Faster%20and%20More%20Efficient%20Bitcoin%20Mining_Rahul_Naik.pdf)

There's a lot of detail in real bitcoin mining which isn't strictly of value in an academic implementation, so I'd suggest doing just the core idea, which is finding a "nonce" for a data block such that it begins with the current "difficulty", or number of zero bits.

1. Take a block of data, perhaps 1 Kbyte or 1 Mbyte
2. Prepend a nonce
3. Compute the SHA256 hash
4. If the hash begins with N zero bits, return this result
5. Select a new nonce
6. Go to step 2

You can get a good idea of problem with this little python program:

```
import hashlib
def bitcoinidea(prefix, msg):
    for nonce in range(0, 0x100000000):
        m = nonce.to_bytes(4, "little") + msg
        h = hashlib.sha256(m).hexdigest()
        print("%08x %s" % (nonce, h))
        if h.startswith(prefix):
            return nonce
    return None

print(bitcoinidea("0000", "fpga".encode()))
```

Which gives you:

```
00000000 23a4ee3fd6e3126b3f01989cc182b4a91ad8979159b275310c16231bbd58e088
00000001 e95728d66e33169e5c08f571372179a274d2e1e039c33ea03591be7737953092
...
000109fb 0000a83516c308986fa508f541faf67573a21e410ade43380e3ed9877a0ef103
68091
```

If you get an FPGA to do the same as that python you'll have done the "Proof-of-Work" function very closely without wasting your time on compatibility with other implementations, which almost certainly would gain no marks in your course.

Comment: Agree...start with hash checking.